# Importing python module from another directory, which then imports a second module from that directory

Tags: python, module

I have a bunch of data processing scripts in the root directory of my Python application that I want to clean up by putting into their own directory, but I can't get it to work properly.

This is my file structure:

```
.
+-- Root
    |
    |-- main_script.py
    |
    +-- utils
    |   |
    |   |-- utilsA.py
    |    `- utilsB.py
    |
    +-- processing_scripts
        |
         `- proccess.py
```

Within `process.py` there is the line `from utils import utilsA as u`, then within `utilsA.py` there is the line `from utils.utilsB import util_function`.

When `process.py` is located in the root directory, this works completely fine, however when I move `process.py` to the `processing_scripts` directory and try to run it from there, it no longer works. It just says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

I did a search and found a number of similar questions on here, the answers to which mostly suggest to use some variant on `sys.path.append('../')`. This solution works if `utilsA.py` has no reference to `utilsB.py`, and I change the line in `process.py` to `from Root.utils import utilsA as u`, but as soon as `utilsA.py` tries to reference `utilsB.py`, it gives the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

Is there a way of tricking `process.py` into thinking it is running from the root directory, so that it can then reference things, which reference other things, without breaking? I can get it to work if I go into `utilsA.py` and add the `sys.path.append('../')` line, as well as changing the reference to `utils.utilsB` to `Root.utils.utilsB`, but I would rather not have to go through and change every single file like that, just to run some processing scripts - and that solution feels incredibly hacky..

Comment: Do note that Python imports _do not_ navigate directories. Imports are only resolved by searching the Python path. If you want `from utils import ...` to work, then `utils` must be a package on the Python path. That is usually accomplished by either installing your project as a distribution project or by ensuring that the directory _containing_ `utils` is your CWD.

Comment: Potentially helpful/related: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: "and try to run it from there, it no longer works." so, since it seems like you haven't packaged/installed this project, then you are relying on the wording directory being added to the path, hence, whether your import works or not depends on where you run it from.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. I did a bit more reading and it seems that my understanding of imports/modules/packages in Python was pretty off. It is not worth turning what I am working on into a full package, so I changed all the import lines that pertain to my files, to relative imports with `.` and `..`, and added `sys.path.append('../')` to my `process.py` script - which seems to work. Thanks again!